# replace multi-line string in java

Tags: java, regex, java-8

Trying to replace multi line string in java using replaceAll method but it's not working. Is there anything wrong with below logic?

```
    String content="      \"get\" : {\n" + 
    "        \"name\" : [ \"Test\" ],\n" + 
    "        \"description\" : \"Test description to replace\",\n" + 
    "        \"details\" : \"Test details\"";


    String searchString="        \"name\" : [ \"Test\" ],\n" + 
"        \"description\" : \"Test description to replace\",";


String replaceString="        \"name\" : [ \"Actual\" ],\n" + 
"        \"description\" : \"Replaced description\",";
```

Tried below options and none of them worked-

```
Pattern.compile(searchString, Pattern.MULTILINE).matcher(content).replaceAll(replaceString);

Pattern.compile(searchString, Pattern.DOTALL).matcher(content).replaceAll(replaceString);

content = content.replaceAll(searchString, replaceString);
```

Comment: I have no way to test this at the moment, but you definitely need to escape the `[` brackets in your search string (change them to `\\[`). Maybe that will already fix it.

Comment: you can quote the whole search string with `\Q` at the beginning or call `Pattern.quote()`

Comment: Use Something like this :  String str = content.replaceAll("\\n","");

Comment: Since you are not using regular expressions, use either the simple `content = content.replace(searchString, replaceString);` or the more complex `content = Pattern .compile(searchString, Pattern.LITERAL).matcher(content).replaceAll(replaceString);`. The latter makes sense if you want to keep the result of `compile` and use it multiple times. Then, you get a benefit from the preparation, e.g. the Boyer–Moore algorithm used behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

> **DISCLAIMER:** You should not use regex to manipulate JSON or XML that have infinite nested content. Finite automate are not adapted to manipulate those data structures and you should use a JSON/XML parser instead.

This being said, purely for learning purpose, I will quickly fix your code.

**1)** Use either `replace` instead of `replaceAll` to avoid that your `searchString` is interpreted as a regex:

```
String content="      \"get\" : {\n" + 
            "        \"name\" : [ \"Test\" ],\n" + 
            "        \"description\" : \"Test description to replace\",\n" + 
            "        \"details\" : \"Test details\"";


String searchString="        \"name\" : [ \"Test\" ],\n" + 
        "        \"description\" : \"Test description to replace\",";


String replaceString="        \"name\" : [ \"Actual\" ],\n" + 
        "        \"description\" : \"Replaced description\",";

System.out.println(content.replace(searchString, replaceString));
```

**output:**

```
  "get" : {
    "name" : [ "Actual" ],
    "description" : "Replaced description",
    "details" : "Test details"
```

**2)** Or use `replaceAll` but escape the brackets to avoid them being interpreted as a character class definition attempt.

```
String searchString="        \"name\" : \\[ \"Test\" \\],\n" + 
        "        \"description\" : \"Test description to replace\",";


String replaceString="        \"name\" : [ \"Actual\" ],\n" + 
        "        \"description\" : \"Replaced description\",";

System.out.println(content.replaceAll(searchString, replaceString));
```

**output:**

```
  "get" : {
    "name" : [ "Actual" ],
    "description" : "Replaced description",
    "details" : "Test details"
```

**Link**: [How to parse JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

- You should load your json structure in an object
- Change the values of the attributes of that object to the new values
- Export it again in json format